# Check article diffusion on social networks via php

Tags: php, analytics, social-networking, html

For our research we are building a database of web pages regarding certain topics. For each of these pages we want to categorize and get some informations about them.

For example one of these information is the diffusion in the social network of the page at a determined t times, let's say one, two and three weeks.

My question is, how can we achieve this?

We thought of watching at the number written next to the social buttons in every page could be a good idea. How would you implement this in php?

Or, are there better ways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to actually and precisely track content dissemination in social networks that I can think of. If those are your sites you want to track, the easiest way would be to use Google Analytics API to get data about social media activity from them.

Comment: The pages are not under my control, so I cannot check them via analytics!

Answer (score 1):

I discovered there are APIs for seeing how much a page has been shared/liked/tweeted/+1ed etc, for every service.

Furthermore exist a service http://www.likeexplorer.com/ that do this for you. Now I just need now to hook up onto their ajax system.

Answer (score 1):

sharedcount.com has an API and PHP examples that look useful and pretty quick to implement.

http://sharedcount.com/documentation.php